# CSS Styling textarea based on rows attribute

Tags: css

Is it possible to style textarea, based on some data attribute like this

```
<textarea type="text" placeholder="Lets do it" cols="50" rows="20" aria-label=" "></textarea>
```

I can only knows that rows attribute will be 20, can i style only that textarea based on rows attribute?

Answer (score 6):

CSS has [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) that take the following format:

```
[attribute_name="attribute_value"]
```

So in your case you could use:

```css
textarea[rows="20"] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<textarea type="text" placeholder="Lets do it" cols="50" rows="20" aria-label=" "></textarea>
```